# Java Thread Stopping Unexpectedly

Tags: java, multithreading

Good evening!

I'm trying to code a Server/Client with java and Sockets.

The process of sending messages is working fine, but I don't know why, after I start the second client and I send a message with the first one, the first client gets stucked and doesn't send the messages anymore.

It has to be a Server-side problem, as I have debugged the whole code and found that the problem in the while, once it leaves it seems id doesn't gets back in again.
My theory is that it is somehow stopped or maybe the iterator just stops functioning.

Could you check it out and give me some guidance? Have spent like 4h on this already.

Thank you very much!

EDIT: So as I have been asked I have reduced the code to what I think is the core of the problem. As I have checked by debugging, when exiting the while, the thread stops by itself.

Server :

```
new Thread() {
            public void run() {

                String inputLine;
                // Input Thread
                    while ((inputLine = clientSocket.read_str()) != null) {
                        // L'iterator ha de començar des del principi cada cop que que es comença el while
                        Iterator<MySocket> keyIterator = connections.keySet().iterator();
                        while (keyIterator.hasNext()) {
                            MySocket sock = keyIterator.next();
                            sock.write_str(inputLine);
                        }
                    }
                    clientSocket.close();

                    removeUser(clientSocket);
            }
        }.start();
```

Comment: We can't just start reading your block of code. Please minimize to the least required code to reproduce your problem, aka [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Edited! Sry for the hassle.

Comment: @Arnau EC it still does not clears up which line is Line 53

Comment: "when the iterator leaves the while" makes no sense whatsoever

Comment: It should be clearer now. What I mean is that once I have 2 clients running, the first one sends one message and then stops working. It is like the thread sleeps or something.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, thing is I was using clientSocket for everythread and I assumed it would work on different clientSockets, but it wasn't, so once the socket was updated, it could only write/read from that socket.

Stupid solution, sorry for the waste of time.

Thanks everyone.